# Populate a column based on previous value and row Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with 5 columns group, date, a, b, and c and I want to do the following:

given df

```
group    date      a    b      c
  a     2018-01    2    3     10
  a     2018-02    4    5     null
  a     2018-03    2    1     null
```

expected output

```
group    date      a    b      c
  a     2018-01    2    3     10
  a     2018-02    4    5     10*3+2=32
  a     2018-03    2    1     32*5+4=164
```

for each group, calculate c by b * c + a and use the output as the c of the next row.

I tried using Lag and window function but couldn't find the right way for this.

Comment: A follow-up question, in case I need the current row b value I can just use the sample logic with the last value? or it won't work? to be specific to this example instead of 10*3+2=32 I'll do (10*3+2)/5=6.4 (b=5 in this example)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Within a window you cannot access results of a column that you are currently about to calculate. This would force Spark to do the calculations sequentially and should be avoided. Another approach is to transform the recursive calculation `c_n = func(c_(n-1))` into a formula that only uses the (constant) values of `a`, `b` and the first value of `c`:

[image: formula]

All input values for this formula can be collected with a window and the formula itself is implemented as [udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = ...
w=Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('date')
df1 = df.withColumn("la", F.collect_list("a").over(w)) \
  .withColumn("lb", F.collect_list("b").over(w)) \
  .withColumn("c0", F.first("c").over(w))

import numpy as np

def calc_c(c0, a, b):
  if c0 is None:
    return 0.0
  if len(a) == 1:
    return float(c0)
  e1 = c0 * np.prod(b[:-1])
  e2 = 0.0
  for i,an in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    e2 = e2 + an * np.prod(b[i+1:-1])
  return float(e1 + e2)


calc_c_udf= F.udf(calc_c, T.DoubleType())

df1.withColumn("result", calc_c_udf("c0", "la", "lb")) \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------+---+---+----+---------+---------+---+------+
|group|   date|  a|  b|   c|       la|       lb| c0|result|
+-----+-------+---+---+----+---------+---------+---+------+
|    a|2018-01|  2|  3|  10|      [2]|      [3]| 10|  10.0|
|    a|2018-02|  4|  5|null|   [2, 4]|   [3, 5]| 10|  32.0|
|    a|2018-03|  2|  1|null|[2, 4, 2]|[3, 5, 1]| 10| 164.0|
+-----+-------+---+---+----+---------+---------+---+------+
```

Comment: great stuff...you b eat me to it

Comment: Wow ... brilliant!

Comment: Amazing!
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Awesome, saved me a lot of time doing the same thing using pandas df iteration.