# Is there a better way to write / optimize this loop in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, apache-spark-sql

Learning pyspark and would be great to know if I can optimise this even more further.

I have followed this S/O ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002085/populate-a-column-based-on-previous-value-and-row-pyspark)) and was able to optimize one of the process but still Im struggling to figure out is there a better way to solve the below scenario.

The dataframe will be like this

*Partition here is just a group of data and whatever the calculation that is required to generate the columns will be based on from those current partition.*

*the rIETB is calculated based on the price and other non changing columns*

| Date | Date 2 | Partition | Price | factor | rIETB | rIETB_last | cap | rIETB_last<cap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 Nov | 6 Nov | 1 | 5 | 5 | 1.50 | 1.50 | 1 | F => No operation on this set again |
| 6 Nov | 7 Nov | 2 | 5 | 5 | 0.05 | 0.15 | 1 | T |
| 7 Nov | 7 Nov | 2 | 5 | 5 | 0.10 | 0.15 [0.05+0.10] | 1 | T |
| 6 Nov | 8 Nov | 3 | 5 | 5 | 0.04 | 0.17 | 1 | T |
| 7 Nov | 8 Nov | 3 | 5 | 5 | 0.05 | 0.17 | 1 | T |
| 8 Nov | 8 Nov | 3 | 5 | 5 | 0.08 | 0.17 [0.04+0.05+0.08] | 1 | T |

On The second iteration the df will be like this during that price +=factor line, for the rIETB_last<cap condition whenever its true the operation is again repeated, now with the current price i'll update the rIETB that value is derived from other columns which are not important here.

| Date | Date 2 | Partition | Price | factor | rIETB | rIETB_last | cap | rIETB_last<cap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 Nov | 6 Nov | 1 | 5 | 5 | 1.50 | 1.50 | 1 | F |
| 6 Nov | 7 Nov | 2 | 10 | 5 | 0.07 | 0.19 | 1 | T |
| 7 Nov | 7 Nov | 2 | 10 | 5 | 0.12 | 0.19 | 1 | T |
| 6 Nov | 8 Nov | 3 | 10 | 5 | 0.06 | 1.23 | 1 | F |
| 7 Nov | 8 Nov | 3 | 10 | 5 | 0.08 | 1.23 | 1 | F |
| 8 Nov | 8 Nov | 3 | 10 | 5 | 1.09 | 1.23 | 1 | F |

This keeps on continuing until everything in the *rIETB_last<cap* column becomes False, and on each iteration the price value increases by the value mentioned in factor column

```
while True:
  filtered_df = df.filter(rIETB_last<cap)
  if (len(filtered_df) == 0):
      break

  filtered_df.withColumn("price", filtered_df.price + 5);

  filtered_df.withColumn("rIETB_last", # consider an operation like the one mentioned in the previous S/O link is happening here)

  # few more calculations which will generate few columns, this will also decides if the loop will break early, but omitting it for simplicity

  first_if_condition = F.col("rIETB_last") < F.col("capacity")

  filtered_df = filtered_df.withColumn("rIETB_last<cap", \
                                 when((first_if_condition), \
                                 filtered_df["rIETB_last<cap"]) \      
                                 .otherwise(~filtered_df["rIETB_last<cap"]))

  # join back the filtered df to the previous df with updated values overwritten on the old df
```

From the above while loop we are interested in the final price and the aggregated values and the generated values in the final iteration of the while loop all intermediate results are overwritten or not used.

Right now I have implemented this with while loop in spark and used `when / otherwise` to do all those if conditions

I want to know is there any other better spark way to do this, since before knowing the attached S/O implementation my other operation was taking few minutes to complete but now its a breeze.

An idea or some reference links to look or concepts to learn would be even more appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windowing could help.

Comment: 2nd loop not sure i get.

Comment: @thebluephantom yes im still looking for a way and windowing is helping, and i thought of a way to optimize few other calculations so that the while loop will be finishing off quickly, but thats purely on the algorithm which is too big to explain here, anyways I'll add my final findings, thanks

Comment: Very hard to follow 2nd part

Comment: oh, what im trying to achieve is repeat the same operation again and again for the rows whose values are greater than capacity until it goes below the capacity value.

Comment: Well I wouldn’t do such looping in spark

Comment: what do you suggest then ? do you think of offloading this to other framework (then i think i should take spark out of the equation ) or is there any spark way to achieve this without the while loop ? And based on the calculation that while loop will be terminated around 10 loops since most of the time the threshold will be reached by that time, so I can even break it after 10 loops just in case if it doesnt gets terminated.

Comment: even after going through a lot of docs, I believe i cant avoid that while loop but only write the inside logics in a spark optimized way

Comment: Other framework. Not a spark use case. Looping is for iterative ML, and udfs for columns.

Comment: Its python looping and will not scale.

Comment: ah thats a bummer, i ll explore other frameworks and will check if i could write some vectorized udfs since most of the operations inside the while loop can be written in vectorized way.

Comment: im also looking into this S/O just incase if I could :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236290/cacheing-and-loops-in-pyspark

Comment: A far simpler example.

Comment: yes think i ll explore pandas or will try a hybrid solution (pandas + normal python)

Comment: What is the scale of the data?

Comment: right now its ~5gb and in future it might even grow, also what would you suggest ? 
this 5 gb consists of data from 60 sources and if the sources increases the data volume increases and these calculations are independent of each other, thats why i leaned towards spark

Comment: Thats not big data.

Comment: gotcha, thanks btw, thought of exploring pyspark with this

Comment: Yes, but u r missing the point on what Spark is. Pyspark is an interface and other apis running via spark. May be a read of parallel processing.